# Simple addition exmple: Shared memory version of reduction performing slower than global memory

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, reduce, gpu-shared-memory

I have implemented two versions of add. The concept of addition in both is exactly the same. The only difference is that in one code (the first one below) I use global memory, while for the second one I use shared memory. As mentioned in several places, the shared memory version should be faster but for my case, the global memory version is faster. **Please tell me where I am going wrong**. Note: I have a GPU with cc 2.1. Thus, for shared memory, I have 32 banks. As I am using only 16 `int`s in the example, there should be no bank conflicts for my code. **Please let me know if this is correct**.

Global version

```
#include<stdio.h>
__global__ void reductionGlobal(int* in, int sizeArray, int offset){

    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    
    if(tid < sizeArray ){
        if(tid % (offset * 2 ) == 0){
            in[tid] += in[tid+offset];
        }
        
    }

}
int main(){
    int size = 16; // size of present input array. Changes after every loop iteration
    int cidata[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};

    int* gidata;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gidata, size* sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(gidata,cidata, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    int offset = 1; 
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    while(offset < size){
        //use kernel launches to synchronize between different block. syncthreads() will not work
        reductionGlobal<<<4,4>>>(gidata,size,offset);
        offset *=2;
        
    }
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    float elapsedTime; 
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime , start, stop);
    printf("time is %f ms", elapsedTime);
    int* output = (int*)malloc( size * sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(output, gidata, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("The sum of the array using only global memory is %d\n",output[0]);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Shared memory version:

```
#include<stdio.h>

__global__ void computeAddShared(int *in , int *out, int sizeInput){
    extern __shared__ float temp[];

    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int ltid = threadIdx.x;
    temp[ltid] = 0;
    while(tid < sizeInput){
        temp[ltid] += in[tid];
        tid+=gridDim.x * blockDim.x; // to handle array of any size
    }
    __syncthreads();
    int offset = 1;
    while(offset < blockDim.x){
        if(ltid % (offset * 2) == 0){
            temp[ltid] = temp[ltid] + temp[ltid + offset];
        }
        __syncthreads();
        offset*=2;
    }
    if(ltid == 0){
        out[blockIdx.x] = temp[0];
    }
    
}

int main(){
    
    int size = 16; // size of present input array. Changes after every loop iteration
    int cidata[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    
    int* gidata;
    int* godata;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gidata, size* sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(gidata,cidata, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    int TPB  = 4;
    int blocks = 10; //to get things kicked off
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    while(blocks != 1 ){
        if(size < TPB){
            TPB  = size; // size is 2^sth
        }
        blocks  = (size+ TPB -1 ) / TPB;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&godata, blocks * sizeof(int));
        computeAddShared<<<blocks, TPB,TPB>>>(gidata, godata,size);
        cudaFree(gidata);
        gidata = godata;
        size = blocks;
    }
    
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    float elapsedTime; 
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime , start, stop);
    printf("time is %f ms", elapsedTime);
    int *output = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(output, gidata, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    //Cant free either earlier as both point to same location
    cudaFree(godata);
    cudaFree(gidata);
    printf("The sum of the array is %d\n", output[0]);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was also fighting for fastest performance and played with a lot of approaches. Out of Global, page locked global, texture, shared, constant and registers... global memory is my favorite. For dot product I could hit 4 teraFlops on a single Asus GTX260 216 matrix edition.

You need to design your kernel in such a way that the memory access is coalesced. Coalesced global memory is the fastest one.

Comment: Probably the cache hierarchy is working quite well. Try to adjust 16Kb for L1 and 48Kb for shared memory in your second implementation. You can also disable L1 cache and compare results.

Comment: @pQB: How to disable L1 cache

Comment: If you are trying to understand reductions and perform some benchmarks you should start with Nvidia's implementation: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1_1/Website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf

Comment: L1 can be disabled at compile time using (-Xptxas -dlcm=cg). See NVIDIA CUDA C Programming Guide. Section G.4.2. The Fermi™ Compatibility Guide for CUDA Applications and the Tuning CUDA™ Applications for Fermi™ are also recommended.

Comment: @pQB: I am using VS 2008. How to specify this flag in VS2008 environment. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Programmer: are you really benchmarking these codes using an input array with 16 entries?

Comment: @talonmies: yes i am using 16 as that is the size of a half warp and i want to avoid any un intentional bank conflicts for shared memory. WHY do you ask?

Comment: @Programmer: I ask because it means your entire question is nonsense. You can't benchmark code running on a throughput optimized  architecture like the GPU using an input size of 16! Try 16 million. Also I am pretty certain your shared memory version never runs because of a shared memory buffer overflow.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot wrong here. Firstly, some general remarks:

- You are performing a reduction on 16 numbers, which is a ridiculously
  small input size. CUDA has a lot of fixed overheads on both the host
  and device sides. The amount of work you are giving the device to do
  is so small that all you are measuring is those overheads, not GPU
  execution time. The difference between the two codes you are seeing
  is probably only due to increase setup overheads in the case of the
  shared memory version. Certainly nothing to do with the code itself. If you want to measure the actual performance of code, the amount of work you give that code must be sufficiently large to ensure the execution time is much larger than the setup time. Be assured that you have about 5 orders of magnitude too little work for this, even on a small GPU.
- You have mentioned bank conflicts, but this is a straw man on the architecture you are using. Fermi has a completely different shared memory layout compared to older hardware and has only a relatively small problem with bank conflicts. Certainly nothing to worry about in this case.

As for the actual reduction codes themselves:

- If you can't come up with way for the input array to be reduced down
  to one partial sum per thread in a single kernel launch, then you *really* haven't thought
  about the problem enough. Your current approach in both the "global"
  and "shared" versions is desperately inefficient. Parallel reductions are a solved problem and the CUDA SDK ships with an excellent white paper on optmization and performance of reduction on the GPU. You should read it before you do anything else.
- Once you get to the point where you have one partial sum per thread,
  you want to perform a shared memory reduction *per block* to have the
  reduction emit one partial sum per block. This will then require only
  two kernel launches to compute the complete reduction.
- Your "shared" version has a buffer overflow which should cause a
  runtime error. The dynamic shared memory size specified at launch
  time is in *bytes*, not words. If your code had error checking, you
  would already have found this. Fermi has excellent shared memory
  protection, and it will generate a runtime fault if you try and write
  outside of what has been statically or dynamically allocated.

Comment: What do you mean by "way for the input array to be reduced down to one partial sum per thread in a single kernel launch". What do you mean by one partial sum per thread in a single kernel launch? Also, regarding you 2nd point about reduction, am i not alredy  performing a shared memory reduction per block to have the reduction emit one partial sum per block

Comment: I ask for the buffer overflow because I checked using both cuda-memcheck and cudaGetLastError and both returned no error after the kernel executions

Comment: The shared memory size you are specifying in the kernel launch statement is wrong. You need to specify it bytes, not words. You probably don't get an error with 4 threads because the granularity of allocation would be a single cache line/bank. If you used a sensible number of theses per block, you would get an error. As for the other questions, the answer is written in clear English, so all I can say is re-read what I wrote.